# Съезжает один блок на Айфоне (причем не только в Сафари, но и через Хром тоже)

Tags: css, ios, flexbox, scss

В чем может быть проблема? Прописала адаптив, сайт отображается корректно на всех устройствах. Кроме айфона. Причем только один единственный блок. Пробовала не только в Сафари его открыть, но и в Гугл Хром - одна и та же проблема.
1й скрин - на андроиде (как и должно отображаться)
2й скрин с айфона

Вот код который писала для этого блока:

```
.products-more {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: start;
    align-content: start;
    padding-top: 65px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    @media (max-width: 765px) {
      -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding: 0;
      max-width: 350px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    @media (max-width: 375px) {
      max-width: 310px;
    }
}
```

[image: 1й скрин, как должно быть.]

[image: 2й скрин с айфона]

Comment: К CSS-у надо бы ещё и html приложить. А так же все другие стили. А лучше живой пример где-нибудь на codepen.

Comment: P.S. На iOS есть только движок Safari. Все остальные браузеры это «скины» над ним. Так что одинаковый рендеринг в Сафари и Хроме это ожидаемое поведение

Comment: в первую очередь я бы это проверил... `@media (max-width: 765px) {max-width: 350px;}` это если что не жестко фиксированные значения, а лимиты при которых блок может и сжаться.